# Vertical line not extending all the way to top of the table in multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I have a table as follows (it is not complete; two columns are missing on the rows after the headers, but the issue is not there):

```
\begin{tabular}{c:ccccccc|cc}
 \thickhline
   & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\textbf{Metric 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Metric 2}} \\ \hhline{|~---------|} 
     
 \multirow{-2}{*}{\diagbox{\textbf{Foo}}{\textbf{Bar}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{A}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{B}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{C}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{D}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{E}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{F}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Total}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{G}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{F}} \\  \hhline{==========} 

 w & \multicolumn{1}{c}{45.78 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{46.09 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{45.98 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{45.76 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{42.63 (0.33)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{46.65} (0.00)} & 47.10 \\ 
 x & \multicolumn{1}{c}{96.78 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{111.77 (0.76)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{112.26 (0.49)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{111.06 (0.49)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.33 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{113.78} (5.67)} & 120.11 \\ 
 y & \multicolumn{1}{c}{28.37 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{34.23 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{35.97 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{86.23} (10.67)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{69.25 (0.00)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{85.70 (10.40)} & 97.31 \\ 
 z & \multicolumn{1}{c}{235.58 (1.37)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{188.52 (1.49)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{174.74 (3.8)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{178.11 (14.25)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{n/a} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{261.48} (9.6)} & 292.32 \\ \thickhline
\end{tabular}
```

The issue I have is that the vertical line after the 7th column does not extend all the way to the top:

[image: Rendered table]

I have `c|` for **Metric 1** and `c|` for **Total**, so I am not sure why the vertical line does not extend all the way to the top. It's not the `diagbox` because I replaced that with just regular text and the issue was still there.

Comment: please provide an example that reproduces the problem. including `\documentclass...\end{document}` and definitions for `:` ,`\thickhline`, `hhline,` ...

Comment: I found that this is actually a limitation of `booktabs` because it takes a stance against using vertical rules. I ended up removing the vertical line entirely.